# react-native-ui-kitten button with multiline text

Tags: react-native, react-native-ui-kitten

I use react-native-ui-kitten library: https://akveo.github.io/react-native-ui-kitten/#/docs/ui-components/rkbutton .
And would like to make `RkButton` to wrap my long text into the several lines. But don't know how to do that.

Currently this:

```
<RkButton
  style={{ backgroundColor: "red", margin: 5 }}
  rkType="xlarge"
>
  Very very very long text Very very very long text Very very very long text Very very very long text
</RkButton>
```

Is being displayed as this:
[image: text is not wrapped]

I want that it wraps the text into the next line(s).

Here is the demo snack: https://snack.expo.io/HkMDcBpd4 .

Any thoughts?

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

I received some help in the `Reactiflux` discord. It turned out, that the only thing missing was `height: auto` in the `RkButton` style.

```
<RkButton style={{ backgroundColor: "red", margin: 5, height: 'auto' }} rkType="xlarge">
        Very long text Very long text Very long text Very long text Very long text
</RkButton>
```

Here is a snack: https://snack.expo.io/HJbHLLpO4 .

Comment: can I do the same height:'auto' for the text in react native?